# Why does std::make_pair not return a pair? Or does it?

Tags: c++, c++11, std-pair, static-assert

My internal sanity check failed so I'm rerunning it on Stackoverflow.

The following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <utility>

int main()
{
    constexpr auto pair_of_ints = std::make_pair(1, 2);
    std::cerr << typeid(pair_of_ints).name();
    //static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(pair_of_ints), std::pair<int, int>>::value, "WTF");
}
```

produces the mangled symbol name for `std::__1::pair<int, int>` on my system (XCode Clang 8.x).

If I then enable the `static_assert`, it fails. I have no idea why.
How can I make this work? I have a function that returns a pair or tuple depending on the arguments passed to it and would like to verify it actually returns a pair or tuple in the correct cases.

Comment: Hint: `pair_of_ints` is `const`.

Comment: You might use something like `template <typename> struct DebugType;`, and then `DebugType<decltype(pair_of_ints)> d;` to have error message with real type.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You declared `pair_of_ints` as `constexpr` which implies `const`:

[[dcl.constexpr]#9](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#9)

> A `constexpr` specifier used in an object declaration declares the object as `const`.

So the type of `pair_of_ints` is actually:

```
const std::pair<int, int>
```

`typeid` ignores cv-qualifiers, which is why this information does not appear in the name:

[[expr.typeid]#5](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.typeid#5)

> If the type of the expression or *type-id* is a cv-qualified type, the result of the `typeid` expression refers to a `std::type_info` object representing the cv-unqualified type.

You could either test against the const-qualified type, or drop the const-qualifier using [std::remove_const_t](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_cv):

```
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(pair_of_ints), 
                           const std::pair<int, int>>::value);
static_assert(std::is_same<std::remove_const_t<decltype(pair_of_ints)>, 
                           std::pair<int, int>>::value);
```

Comment: It is also possible to remove CV qualifiers in a type (since C++11) using [std::remove_cv](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_cv)

Comment: @JorgeBellón -- just for completeness, it was possible to remove CV qualifiers from a type before C++11. It's a fairly straightforward use of templates. C++11 added those templates to the standard library, making them more readily accessible.

Comment: @PeteBecker you are right. I actually messed with the wording by putting the reference to the standard before the link and not afterwards.